# Preg Split not working if use variable in pattern

Tags: php, preg-split

I have string like this and i want to split with matched pattern

```
$string = '[(123,234,34)tes2t.jpg*@*test.jpg]';//dynamic no of files
```

so if i try like this,

```
$keywords =preg_split( "/(?<=test.jpg)/", $string,'-1');
```

it is working but i need to pass variable in pattern

```
$file = 'test.jpg';
$keywords =preg_split( "/(?<=$file)/", $string,'-1');
```

This is not working.please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does: *is not working* means? Do you get: `PHP warning: Is not working in line xx` ?

Comment: it is not splitting string...it return original string

Comment: [**Can't reproduce your problem**](https://3v4l.org/I6q52) so show us your **real** and **full** code

Comment: Can you update your question to provide an example of your expected output? I ran the code here and I get output... It's hard to know if this is correct, according to your specifications, unless you explicitly state what you expect. Then we can help :)

Comment: For the record, This is what I am getting: `Array
(
    [0] => [(123,234,34)tes2t.jpg*@*test.jpg
    [1] => ]
)`. Additionally, the default flag for `preg_split` is `-1`. So you don't need that in your example. Indeed, you are passing it as a `string` not an `integer`, which **might** have unintended consequences...

Comment: what you need to get from this string `$string = '[(123,234,34)tes2t.jpg*@*test.jpg]';//dynamic no of files`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = 'test.jpg';
$keywords =preg_split( '/(?<='.$file.')/', $string,'-1');
```

Comment: @BhumiShah: do the same and use `preg_quote`

Comment: please provide more information in your response. Explain the posted code is not working and why your solution should help.